# java gridlayout gui - too many panels?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a board game in Java however i am pretty new to GUI's. The problem is that the coloured panels are being added to the grid layout and so are the images so they end up being packed side by side.

I would like the images to be on top of the other color panels so it looks like a board with pieces (the images), on top.

the following code should create four colored squares with four of the same images on top, instead they just end up side by side.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class test extends JFrame {

private static JPanel gridLayout = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2));
    private static ImageIcon img = new 
ImageIcon(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/images/an_image.png");
private static String[] boardTest = {
        "i", "i", 
        "i", "i" };

public test() {
    BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
    setLayout(layout);
    add(gridLayout);
}

private static JLabel getPieceObject(String strPieceName) {
    JLabel images;
    if (strPieceName.equals("i")) {
        images = new JLabel(img);
    }  else {
        images = new JLabel();
    }
    return images;
}

private static void displayBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        gridLayout.add(getPieceObject(boardTest[i]), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        // this creates the color squares of the board//
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(); //error
          if (i % 2 == i/2 % 2) {
              panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
          } else {
              panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
          }
          gridLayout.add(panel); 
        ////////////////////////////////////////////////
          gridLayout.validate();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    displayBoard();
    test app = new test();
    app.setSize(200, 200);
    app.setVisible(true);
    app.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

}

Comment: You where given the answer to this question in your last posting on this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094318/java-gui-panel-help-please. You never bothered to accept the answer (even though you copied some of the code from the suggestion). I suggested you add the "label" to the "chess square", not the "chess board".

Comment: i tried changing the background color of the lables that contain the images however it didn't work. i think the problem may be that i am using a string array to represent the boad and its pieces so each time i iterator through i create an instance of the same label, with a different image.

Comment: I have no idea what the background has to do with anything. All you do is create an Icon. Add the Icon to a JLabel. Then add the label to the colored panel that represents the square on the board. You still haven't accepted my suggestion from your last posting even though you are using the code I suggested. So you are on your own. I'm not going to repeat myself a third time.

Comment: what code? the set border layout? thats because i stated again using a frame setup from a different project of mine. if you would like me to select it as correct i will.

Comment: Well, the suggestion was given before you started a different project. If you aren't going to listen to the suggestions given, then why should we even attempt to make suggestions? If you didn't understand the suggestions, then why didn't you ask a question instead of creating a whole new posting. When you create a new posting people waste time because they don't know what has already been suggestion and usally make the same suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You could set the image as the background of the panel, [like so](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Panelwithbackgroundimage.htm).

Comment: I've tried adding an image as a background but it always just paints over the frame of the board.

Comment: You can maybe try to set the layoutmanager to null, this will give you complete control on where and how things are displayed. This link:http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/ZOrder.htm  gives you an example of such process. You can first draw the background panels and then draw the images after that.

Comment: i'll try that later. I think the biggest problem that i am having is that you cannot extend JFrame and JPanel at the same time, and i am still new to the gui layout of java.

Comment: There is no need to extend either the JFrame or the JPanel since you are not adding any new functionality to either component.